# Powershell Key/Value Pair Matching Problem

Tags: powershell

I am looking to check a key value pair in powershell. I have tried various methods but none seem to be working as I would expect.

I keep getting a `True` response on a lookup of `$checked_group`, even though I can see the KeyValue pair in the write-out.

`if (!($checked_groups[$varDomain] -eq "$varName"))`

Even if the keyValue pair is in the `$checked_groups` dictionary the above statement is `True`. Have you ever come across this before?

I cant recreate the problem using the snippet below even though its pretty much the same logic as my live code. The sources of the values are different, as I am dynamically collecting these in the live code. And iterating over them in a loop, my `$checked_groups = @{ }` is outside this loop to maintain the dict key/pairs across all iterations and I can confirm they are preserved across ever iteration.

I can't work out why this statement would always resolve to `True` :(

```
$checked_groups = @{ }
$varDomain = "example.com"
$varName = "Administrator"

if (!($checked_groups[$varDomain] -eq "$varName"))
{
    write-host 'Not In There'
}

foreach ($thing in $checked_groups)
{
    Write-Host ($thing | Out-String)
}

$checked_groups += @{$varDomain = $varName}

if (($checked_groups[$varDomain] -eq "$varName"))
{
    write-host 'In There'
    foreach ($thing in $checked_groups)
    {
        Write-Host ($thing | Out-String)
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug by replacing `!()` with `$foo -ne $bar` and assigning values into intermediate variables to see in which step it goes haywire.

Comment: Do you mean create some newVariable and create a statement with `($checked_groups[$varDomain] -neq "$varName"))` ?

Comment: Ok I think... I have worked it out. For some reason this `$checked_groups += @{$varDomain = $varName}` seems to be temperamental. I changed it to `.Add()` and it seems to be behaving. Will update again once I've gathered more data.

Comment: No, something like `$foo = $checked_groups[$varDomain]` and `if($foo -ne $varName`, so you can double-check the variable values by printing or using ISE. Adding characters around print statements helps to catch extra whitespace, like in `write-host "foo is /$foo/`

Comment: I would recommend changing how you are accessing and updating the dictionary. Use `$dictionary["keyExistsOrNot"] = "value"`.  If it exists, it will update the value otherwise create a new value. You dont have to go through all the if else statements

Comment: @Jawad If it doesnt exist I want to carry out a different flow so I dont think that will work